# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left [\tan \frac{\pi}{2n}\tan \frac{2\pi}{2n}..\tan \frac{n\pi}{2n}\right]^{1/n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

$$\ln y = \lim _{n\to \infty} \frac 1n \left [\ln (\tan \frac{\pi}{2n})+....\ln (\tan \frac{n\pi}{2n}) \right]$$
$$\ln y = \int _0^1 \ln (\tan \frac{\pi x}{2}).dx$$

Now this integral is a pain to solve, and online calculators aren’t able to solve it, so is this method even correct? If yes, then how do I solve the integral, and if not, what is the correct way?

Comment: The integral is improper, with the integrand undefined at $x=1$. So it's not appropriate to try to calculate its value using a right-hand Riemann sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1\ln (\tan \frac{\pi (1-x)}{2})dx=\int_0^1\ln (\cot \frac{\pi x}{2})dx$$

$$I+I=\int_0^1\ln (\cot \frac{\pi x}{2})dx+\int_0^1\ln (\tan \frac{\pi x}{2})dx=\int_0^1\ln (1)dx=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Assuming the final $\tan(\frac{n\pi}{2n})$ isn't there (that being $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}=\infty$), just use $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=\cot\theta$

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

SInce you already received good answer and comments, let me address the problem of the antiderivative about which you write

*"this integral is a pain to solve, and online calculators aren’t able to solve it"*

In fact, it is quite simple : let $\tan \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)=t$

$$I=\int \log (\tan \frac{\pi x}{2})\,dx=\frac 2\pi \int \frac{\log (t)}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$\frac{1}{t^2+1}=\frac{1}{(t+i)(t-i)}=\frac i 2\left(\frac{1}{t+i}-\frac{1}{t-i} \right)$$
$$I=\frac i \pi\left(\int \frac{\log(t)}{t+i}dt-\int \frac{\log(t)}{t-i}dt \right)$$
$$I=\frac i \pi\left(\Big[\text{Li}_2(i t)+\log (1-i t) \log (t)\Big]-\Big[\text{Li}_2(-i t)+\log (1+i t) \log (t)\Big]\right)$$
$$I=\frac 1 \pi\Big[2 \log (t) \tan ^{-1}(t)+i (\text{Li}_2(i t)-\text{Li}_2(-i t)) \Big]$$

Comment: I am not very comfortable with using complex numbers, but your answer is very helpful in solving for the future. Ofc, I tried to solve the integral manually rather then using the short cuts for definite integrals, hence my post here.

Comment: @Aditya. Complex numbers are fantastic ! However, I remember my troubles when I started learning about them (63+ years ago !). So, don't worry ! Cheers

Comment: Well, by not being comfortable I meant this is the first time I am seeing complex numbers being used like that, so I wanted to thank you for introducing me to greater applications :)